# errors script in R studio

Tags: r

I found this error when running a script on R studio:

```
Error in cell_limits(c(get_row(path, "outcome full name"), outcome_column), :
  length(ul) == 2L is not TRUE
```

How could I resolve it?

Thank you

I want to resolve this error on R studio

Comment: Welcome to SO, Amira Messadi! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (please be explicit about non-base packages), sample representative data (perhaps via `dput(head(x))` or building data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`), possibly stochastically), perhaps actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: More specifically, we don't know what packages you're using, what expression you used that triggered this error, nor what arguments you passed to it. (This might be `cellranger` and/or `readxlsb`, but I'm not sure.)

Comment: I am using these libraries :  library(meta)
library(metafor)
library(readxl)
library(tibble)
library(LaplacesDemon)
library(dplyr)
library("grid")

Comment: perhaps, I have an error in my excel file? what is the meaning of  length(ul) == 2L is not TRUE?

Comment: it means that some object named `ul`, whether created by you or as an argument or object calc'd with functions you called, is supposed to be a vector of length 2 and is not. Having said all that, it can be anywhere, and not knowing how you triggered it ... there's not much we can do.